# how to increment like counter when post is shared in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to have a like button and also share button on the articles in my website, what i want is that readers can like the article and also if anyone share's the article it should increment the like counter.

So is there any plugin in wordpress with which i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can achieve this using kk star plugin.

plugin link : `https://wordpress.org/plugins/kk-star-ratings/`

Comment: the plugin have star rating what i need is a like button similar to facebook.

Comment: for like button you can use this plugin : KK i Like it. url : https://wordpress.org/plugins/kk-i-like-it/